# document.getElementsByTagName not working

Tags: javascript, tags

I would like to use `document.getElementsByTagName('input')`
to set as required (or unset it) for a list of inputs.
is it possible?

I've tried:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input').required = false;
```

or (for a different purpose)

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input').value = ""
```

but it doesn't seem work.

Moreover: is it possible to catch a certain type of input (i.e. text or radio)?

Thank you!!!
ObOnKen

Comment: It returns an HTMLCollection https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a collection of elements so you need to iterate over the collection...

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    if(elements[i].type == "text")
    {
        elements[i].value = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).  If you want to do something to each item returned, you'll have to explicitly iterate across them:

```
var inputs = table.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { 
    inputs[i].required = false;
}
```

However, if you use some libraries, you may be able to operate on each of the contents of a collection (or, as some of the libraries call them, selection) en-masse with a syntax as you seem to expect.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `for` loop for iterating all `input`s, because `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a `HTMLCollection` of elements with the given tag name.

```
var values = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    values[i].required = false;
}
```

To catch a certain type of input:

```
var textInput = document.querySelector("input[type=text]");
```

`querySelector` returns the first element within the document.

Comment: Just using `querySelector` rather than `getElementsByTagName` solved my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple input elements in your document,then you use document.getElementByTagName:for this you've to use for loop to iterate over multiple elements.
or if you've only one element then you can use queryselector with given Id/Classname like:if you've I'd in your element:document.querySelector("idname"); or you've class in your element: document.querySelector("className");

You can also use (in case of one element) document.getElementById("idname");  if you've given Id to your element