# Add expression translate="no" in the HTML tag using JS

Tags: javascript, html, tags, google-translate

How can I add in the  tag the expression translate="no", using JavaScript?

The tag should be like this:

Tried the code below:

var root = document.getElementsByTagName( 'html');
root.setAttribute( 'translate', 'no' );

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661807/document-getelementsbytagname-not-working

Comment: Not that helpful.

Comment: Your mistake is thinking that `root` has a setAttribute method (it’s a collection not an element).

Comment: Continuing on from James' comment (and apologizing if I'm telling you something that you already know): using `document.getElementsByTagName( 'html')` will return a `collection`, or an array of objects. For example, when you say `document.getElementsByTagName( 'input')`, you're getting all the inputs available in the current DOM state, and they're all nicely packed in an array, which you can read through a loop, or by a specific index. To understand it better, open up the developer console in your browser, and note what the result of `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName( 'html'))` is.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add it individually, using the code below. It's an option, but not the prettiest.

```
document.getElementById("myID").setAttribute("translate", "no");
```